# Emacs GUI won't start when launched from the Terminal

Tags: terminal, emacs

When I type

```
brew install emacs
```

at the Terminal, the following message displays:

```
Warning: emacs 25.3 is already installed
```

However, when I type

```
emacs &
```

the only thing that happens is that the following message is displayed:

```
[1] 21302
```

but the Emacs GUI isn't launched. I have another apple computer where typing

```
emacs &
```

launches the Emacs GUI. How can I make the Emacs GUI launch by executing a command from the Terminal?

---

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

Comment: What is the result of `type emacs` on both systems? Is `.emacs` the same?

Comment: @patrix: The result is `emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs` on both systems.

Comment: @patrix: `.emacs` is the same: I've just copied it from the "well-behaved" computer to the "troublesome" computer.

Comment: What happens if you start emacs in the foreground? Any error messages or such?

Comment: @patrix: Emacs starts inside the Terminal window as a console application.

Comment: Ok. If you run `emacs &`, does the emacs process keep running or terminate on its own after some time? Can you Cmd-Tab into the window or does it not show up in the list? Does it consume CPU time (check with top or Activity Monitor)? Does it work if you run `emacs -q &` or `emacs -Q &`? What else have you already tried?

Comment: @patrix: If I run `emacs &` the Emacs process keeps running. It does not seem to terminate on its own after some time. It does not show up in the Cmd-Tab list. It is listed on the Activity Monitor list, but consumes 0.00 CPU time. It does not work if I run `emacs -q &` nor if I run `emacs -Q &`. If I execute `emacs` as a foreground process in the Terminal of the other, "well-behaved", computer, the Emacs GUI launches.

Comment: Does it work if you create a new user account? Is software installed on one Mac which isn‘t on the other (eg X11 or TeX)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67106/discussion-between-patrix-and-evan-aad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation command should end with the option `--with-cocoa`:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

But first execute

```
brew uninstall emacs
```

or else Homebrew will refuse to reinstall Emacs.

As an alternative to `brew install emacs --with-cocoa`, Homebrew recommends running

```
brew cask install emacs
```

(you get this recommendation in the end of the `brew install emacs --with-cocoa` run). However, I've found that this doesn't work, and ends with the following error message:

> Error: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/Emacs.app'.

---

**Update as of July 23 2019**: The `--with-cocoa` option and the `cask install` command are not supported any longer. Follow these steps:

1. `brew uninstall emacs`
2. `rm -rf /Applications/Emacs.app/z`
3. `brew install emacs --cask`

*Acknowledgements*

This answer is essentially copied from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36158/4084).

---